# Android Java Starting an activity if a condition is true

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would like to start an activity only if the string I pass with putExtra from another activity equals 'search' like so:

```
        action = intent.getStringExtra("cause");
        Button btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(action == "search") {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(profiloutente.this, ricerca.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }

            }
        });
```

But, the condition always seems to be false (so the activity doesn't start) even if the variable containing the get Extra equals "search". I don't understand why this happens. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious probklem is that you are using `==` on a `String`. [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Another problem is that `action` is read outside of listener. That may be the intent, but I can't tell in isolation - if it is the surrounding the entire listener in the `if` statement would make more sense. `action` will take the value from `getStringExtra` at the time you run the surrounding code, not when the listener is fired.

There may be other issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(action.equals("search"))
```

instead

```
if(action == "search")
```